# Is there a way to map the pop-up toolbar to a Middle Click + Right Click shortcut?

Tags: shortcut

I've been looking at the keymap and trying to see if it was possible but i've been unable to find out. I'm rather new to Blender so I might just be misunderstanding the software.

I'm trying to map it like this to ease myself into the program, this is the same shortcut I use to access the edit tools within the music software FL Studio and I figured this would be an easy way to keep the amount of keys I've got to learn down. Just do it the way I do it in the other program you know? :)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Right click brings up a context-sensitive menu in most screens anyway so I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to map the Pop-up Toolbar, the one that currently shows with the shortcut Shift+Spacebar, to Middle Click + Right Click. The Context Menu unfortunately does not contain the tools located on the left hand side of the 3D Viewport, the Pop-up Toolbar has these instead, hence why i'd like to map it to the shortcut above.

I hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In 2.93) Edit -> Preferences, keymap group, window leaf, click "Add New" and edit the new entry at the bottom to mouse Button4 or another custom button. Mapping the "middle + right" chord to Button4 has to be done in third party software at the system level (like razer or logitech) and doesn't appear to be an option in the default windows mouse driver.

If you don't have software to map custom buttons, a fallback would be adding a key modifier (e.g. ctrl+middle) but of course that isn't what you asked for in the question.[image]